# Pandas Groupby: get value from previous element of a group based on value of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with 4 columns. I have sorted this data frame by 'group' and 'timestamp' beforehand.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "type": ['type0', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type1', 'type3', 'type0', 'type1', 'type3', 'type3'],
    "group": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "timestamp": ["20220105 07:52:46", "20220105 07:53:11", "20220105 07:53:55", "20220105 07:59:12", "20220105 08:24:13", "20220105 08:48:19", "20220105 11:01:30", "20220105 11:15:16", "20220105 12:13:36", "20220105 12:19:44"],
    "price": [0, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 0.5, 3, 3.25, pd.NA]
})

>> df
    type  group          timestamp price
0  type0      1  20220105 07:52:46     0
1  type1      1  20220105 07:53:11   1.5
2  type2      1  20220105 07:53:55   2.5
3  type3      1  20220105 07:59:12     3
4  type1      1  20220105 08:24:13   3.2
5  type3      1  20220105 08:48:19   3.1
6  type0      2  20220105 11:01:30   0.5
7  type1      2  20220105 11:15:16     3
8  type3      2  20220105 12:13:36  3.25
9  type3      2  20220105 12:19:44  <NA>
```

After grouping by the column 'group', I want to create a 'new_price' column as per the following logic: 
For each 'type3' row in a group (i.e., df['type'] = 'type3'), get the price from the PREVIOUS 'type1' or 'type2' row in the group.
For type0/type1/type2 rows, keep the same price as in the input data frame.

**My Solution:**

My solution below works when we don't have 2 consecutive 'type3' rows. **But when there are 2 consecutive 'type3' rows, I get the wrong price for the second 'type3' row.** I want the price from the previous 'type1' or 'type2' row in the group, but I get the price from the first 'type3' row using my solution.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["group", "timestamp"])
required_types_mask = df['type'].isin(['type1', 'type2', 'type3'])
temp_series = df.loc[:, 'price'].where(required_types_mask).groupby(df['group']).shift(1)
type_3_mask = df['type'].eq('type3')
df.loc[:, 'new_price'] = df.loc[:, 'price'].mask(type_3_mask, temp_series)
```

**My result:**

```
    type  group          timestamp price new_price
0  type0      1  20220105 07:52:46     0         0
1  type1      1  20220105 07:53:11   1.5       1.5
2  type2      1  20220105 07:53:55   2.5       2.5
3  type3      1  20220105 07:59:12     3       2.5
4  type1      1  20220105 08:24:13   3.2       3.2
5  type3      1  20220105 08:48:19   3.1       3.2
6  type0      2  20220105 11:01:30   0.5       0.5
7  type1      2  20220105 11:15:16     3         3
8  type3      2  20220105 12:13:36  3.25         3
9  type3      2  20220105 12:19:44  <NA>       3.25 <- Incorrect price
```

**Expected result:**

```
    type  group          timestamp price new_price
0  type0      1  20220105 07:52:46     0         0
1  type1      1  20220105 07:53:11   1.5       1.5
2  type2      1  20220105 07:53:55   2.5       2.5
3  type3      1  20220105 07:59:12     3       2.5
4  type1      1  20220105 08:24:13   3.2       3.2
5  type3      1  20220105 08:48:19   3.1       3.2
6  type0      2  20220105 11:01:30   0.5       0.5
7  type1      2  20220105 11:15:16     3         3
8  type3      2  20220105 12:13:36  3.25         3
9  type3      2  20220105 12:19:44  <NA>         3 <- Correct price
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `mask` the price with type3 then `ffill`

```
s = df.price.mask(df.type.isin(['type0','type3']))
df['new'] = np.where(df.type.eq('type3'),s.groupby(df['group']).ffill(),df['price'])
df
    type  group          timestamp price  new
0  type0      1  20220105 07:52:46     0    0
1  type1      1  20220105 07:53:11   1.5  1.5
2  type2      1  20220105 07:53:55   2.5  2.5
3  type3      1  20220105 07:59:12     3  2.5
4  type1      1  20220105 08:24:13   3.2  3.2
5  type3      1  20220105 08:48:19   3.1  3.2
6  type0      2  20220105 11:01:30   0.5  0.5
7  type1      2  20220105 11:15:16     3    3
8  type3      2  20220105 12:13:36  3.25    3
9  type3      2  20220105 12:19:44  <NA>    3
```

Comment: I used the same approach ;) however you need to ensure that there is never a type0 right before a type3 or you'll get the wrong `ffill`

Comment: @mozway ah updated ~, thx

Comment: Thank you Beny and @mozway for the help. Both your solutions work really well. I just changed the first mask to 
s = df.price.where(df.type.isin(['type1','type2'])) because I might have other types in my data as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a series of masks to [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html).

First mask 'type3' and 'type0' (the latter to avoid using it as source to `ffill`). Then restore the values of 'type0'.

All is done per group.

```
df['new_price'] = (
 df.groupby('group')
   .apply(lambda d: d['price']
            .mask(d['type'].isin(['type3', 'type0'])) # type0/3 to NaN
            .ffill()                                  # fill with previous type1/2
            .mask(d['type'].eq('type0'), d['price'])  # restore type0
         )
   .values
 )
```

output:

```
    type  group          timestamp price new_price
0  type0      1  20220105 07:52:46     0         0
1  type1      1  20220105 07:53:11   1.5       1.5
2  type2      1  20220105 07:53:55   2.5       2.5
3  type3      1  20220105 07:59:12     3       2.5
4  type1      1  20220105 08:24:13   3.2       3.2
5  type3      1  20220105 08:48:19   3.1       3.2
6  type0      2  20220105 11:01:30   0.5       0.5
7  type1      2  20220105 11:15:16     3       3.0
8  type3      2  20220105 12:13:36  3.25       3.0
9  type3      2  20220105 12:19:44  <NA>       3.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mozway. This worked well. Your comments really helped too!